# Show that some serie is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose I have a sequence $(x_t)$ such that

$$|x_t|\leq B,\quad \forall t \in \mathbb{N}$$

e $\beta \in (0,1)$. I would like to show that the following sequence is convergent

$$\sum_{t = 0}^{\infty} \beta^t x_t$$

First, it is immediate that $|\sum_{t = 0}^{\infty} \beta^t x_t| \leq \frac{B}{1-\beta}$.  Note that if I have that $x_t \geq 0$, I can use that the parcial sum sequence $s_n = \sum_{t = 0}^{n} \beta^t x_t $ is monotone and conclude the convergence. But, $x_t$ can take negative values.

So, how Can I prove that the serie is convergent?

Comment: Just show absolute convergence and this will imply regular convergence, i.e. just show that $\sum_{t=0}^\infty \beta^t|x_t|$ converges.

Comment: Perfect, I was not remembering that result. Thanks.